# How to compare each integer in 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays

This is my assignment:

> Assume U = {1 , . . . ,10 }. Write a Java program which lets you enter a pair of sets A & B from the keyboard, then computes and prints their union and intersection. Remember that the sets of A and B must be a subset of the U(universe) set.

Right now my main concern is how to compare each index from the two arrays I have. If the indexes match, then I need it  to be true, otherwise if they don't match, I need it to be false. I just don't know how to compare the two so if someone could give me some guidance, that'd be great. (I realize I don't have anywhere in my code comparing the two, I just am unsure of where to begin with it).

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class sets {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      //Declare the variables
      int [] universe = new int[10];

      //Ask the user for the numbers in set A
      System.out.print("How many numbers do you want in the first set? ");
      int num1 = console.nextInt();
      int [] A = new int [num1];
      int i = 0;
      while (i < num1) {
         System.out.print("Please enter an integer 1-10: ");
         int numA = console.nextInt();
         A[i++] = numA;
      }

      //Ask the user for the numbers in set B  
      System.out.print("How many numbers do you want in the second set? ");
      int num2 = console.nextInt();
      int [] B = new int [num2];
      int j = 0;
      while (j < num2) {
         System.out.print("Please enter an integer 1-10: ");
         int numB = console.nextInt();
         B[j++] = numB;
      }


      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(B));
   }
}
```

Comment: why do you use arrays ? collection.Set are much more appropriate in your case.

Comment: It's just what my professor wants to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Declare two methods

`private static int[] union(int[] s1, int[] s2)`

and

`private static int[] intersection(int[] s1, int[] s2)`

See if you can generate their return values
from the `int[]` values (i.e. the sets) passed in.

Alternatively, you can avoid all the trouble, and just use
`HashSet<Integer>` instead of `int[]` for representing your
sets. But I guess you want to do everything yourself which is
better (as this is just an exercise).

Comment: add a function `boolean isIn(int[] s, int value)`, which should probably be used

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: As this is apparently a homework, I will not post any code per se.

The first thing you need to do is define the 3 notions you use in this exercise:

- A `set` is a group of elements such as each element is present only once
- An intersection is a `set` of element present in `group` A or in `group` B
- An union is a `set` of element present both in `group` A and in `group` B

Then you need to define what basic functions you will need.

- tell if an element E is present in a set A.
- add an element to a `set`.

Now, looking at what you have so far, the issue is that you are creating 2 groups A and B that are not sets. There is nothing preventing to have a group like so `[1, 1, 1]`

Therefore, you first work should be to make sure each group remains a set, by checking the content of the set before adding a value. That uses the first function defined earlier.

Once A and B are both `sets`, you need to find an algorithm for each of the functions that are asked of you.

The union algorithm is quite simple:

- Loop on the elements of each of the groups that you want to add to the union, if the element is not in the set already, add it.

The intersection is not very much complicated:

- Loop on the elements of each of the groups that you want to add to the union, if the element is not in the set already, and is present in all the groups that you are intersecting, add it.

All this should fit in around 20 lines, 30 tops.

Comment: I appreciate it, and like I said, I was just looking for guidance, not the answer. Because it doesn't help to just get the answer. I will look over what you said and try to compute it. Thank you !